# Bootstrap Transparent Navbar - Mobile Collapsed Menu Icons Disappear

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, transparent

After finally getting the navbar to look the way I want - slighty transparent black with white links - the collapsed icons don't show up on mobile. The link is there and functioning, but no icon. What am I missing here?

Here's the navbar:

```
    <nav class="navbar transparent navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <nav class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-nav-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">EMILY STEWART VIOLIN</a></div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
              <li><a href="music.html">MUSIC</a></li>
              <li><a href="pedagogy.html">PEDAGOGY</a></li>
              <li><a href="blog.php">BLOG</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </nav>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.navbar.transparent .navbar-inner {
       background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
       color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar.transparent .navbar-inner li a {
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: "Raleway";
        font-size: 10pt;
        letter-spacing: 3pt;
    }
    .navbar.transparent .nav > li > a:focus,
    .navbar.transparent .nav > li > a:hover {
      color: #666666;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    .button.navbar-toggle.collapsed:focus,
    .button.navbar-toggle.collapsed:hover {
      color: #666666;
    }
    .navbar.transparent .navbar-brand:hover, 
     .navbar.transparent .navbar-brand:focus {
      background-color: transparent;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar.transparent .navbar-brand{
      background-color: transparent;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-family: "Tenor Sans";
      font-size: 16pt;
      letter-spacing: 1pt;
    }
```

And here's my site: [Site](http://www.emilystewartviolin.com/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you made the toggle button transparent as well. Simply replace this:

```
.navbar-toggle {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

with this:

```
.navbar-toggle {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    background-color: #fc0 /* change this to any color you want! */;
}
```

Comment: that's actually the bootstrap css used to style the button, not something the op added

Comment: I never said she added that, I just gave her the solution. Since CSS styles are applied in cascades, if she changes a parent style (like she did), she needs to change things down the cascade

Comment: Thank you- this worked fine for me! I figured it was a simple styling thing but couldn't figure out the exact code.

Comment: Nice to hear :) if it was of use for you, please mark the answer as accepted so it doesn't show as unresolved and can benefit other users

Answer (score 3):

You need to include either the `.navbar-default` or `.navbar-inverse` class on your `nav` element to generate the proper bootstrap styling. Otherwise you'll need to style the button yourself.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default transparent navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

or

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse transparent navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

Check the examples in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).